# Factory to create default or cyphered and encoded output marshalers

Tags: go

The following code bellow is a factory which creates two different objects for `marshalling` `cyphered` and `encoded` output or the plain text `default` output. I'm concerned with a few things:

- different switch arms may have different dependencies, e.g.`c.createCyphered(pgpPublicKey)` vs `c.createDefault()`
- The `pgpPublicKey`, `cypher` and `enc` params are all available **at runtime** on a per request basis. The public key is retrieved from the db per user, so it cannot be retrieved at application init stage.
- `Cypher` and `Encoder` at the moment are only used by `c.createCyphered`, but in not so distant future there could be new implementations added.
- at the moment the arms conditions sometimes rely on two params `pgpPublicKey` and `cypher` and sometimes on three, including two aforementioned plus `enc`

```
// CreatorFn creates a concrete marshaller to handle the provided msg.
type CreatorFn func(msg dto.Response) (json.Marshaler, error)

// Creator is a factory which creates concrete marshalling strategies to handle the given msg.
type Creator struct{}

// New creates a new instance of Creator.
func New() *Creator {
    return &Creator{}
}

// Create creates a concrete marshaller.CreatorFn.
//
// The following rules are applied:
//   - No PGP Public Key given and the `cypher=openpgp` -> returns vem.ErrPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided
//   - PGP Public Key given and `cypher=off` -> replies error vem.ErrNoCypherSpecified
//   - PGP Public Key given and `cypher=openpgp` -> returns Cyphered vem.CreatorFn.
//   - No PGP Public Key given and the `cypher=off`-> returns Default vem.CreatorFn.
//   - If the `cypher=openpg` then the enc must be `hex'
//   - It wraps any failures with vem.ErrCannotCreateMarshaller.
func (c *Creator) Create(cypher enum.Cypher, enc enum.Enc, pgpPublicKey string) (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    switch {
    case pgpPublicKey == "" && cypher == enum.CypherOpenPGP:
        return c.errPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided()
    case pgpPublicKey != "" && cypher == enum.CypherOff:
        return c.errNoCypherSpecified()
    case pgpPublicKey != "", cypher == enum.CypherOpenPGP && enc == enum.EncHex:
        return c.createCyphered(pgpPublicKey)
    case pgpPublicKey == "" && cypher == enum.CypherOff:
        fallthrough // fallthrough to default marshaller
    default:
        return c.createDefault()
    }
}

func (c *Creator) createCyphered(pgpPublicKey string) (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    encryptor := openpgp.New(openpgp.WithPublicKey(pgpPublicKey))
    encoder := hexenc.New(hexenc.WithZeroPrefix(), hexenc.WithUpperCase())

    return marshaller.CreateCyphered(encryptor, encoder), nil
}

func (c *Creator) createDefault() (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    return marshaller.CreateDefault(), nil
}

func (c *Creator) errPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided() (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    return nil, merry.Wrap(vem.ErrCannotCreateMarshaller, merry.WithCause(vem.ErrPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided))
}

func (c *Creator) errNoCypherSpecified() (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    return nil, merry.Wrap(vem.ErrCannotCreateMarshaller, merry.WithCause(vem.ErrNoCypherSpecified))
}
```

Comment: Are there `import` statements that are relevant to this code?

Comment: No, not really. `merry` is just an error handling library. `enum` package has conventional `iota-based` enums for `Cypher` and `Encoder` types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it another though I've refactored the code in the following fashion:

- extracted the switch branch conditions into separate functions
- got rid of switch by using an array of rules.

The result is pretty similar to the following:

```
// Creator is a factory which creates concrete marshalling strategies to handle the given msg.
type Creator struct{}

// New creates a new instance of Creator.
func New() *Creator {
    return &Creator{}
}

type (
    cond     func() bool
    strategy func() (vem.CreatorFn, error)
    rule     struct {
        cond     cond
        strategy strategy
    }
)

// Create creates a concrete marshaller.CreatorFn.
//
// The following rules are applied:
//   - No PGP Public Key given and the `cypher=openpgp` -> returns vem.ErrPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided
//   - PGP Public Key given and `cypher=off` -> replies error vem.ErrNoCypherSpecified
//   - PGP Public Key given and `cypher=openpgp` -> returns OpenPGP Cyphered and Hex Encoded vem.CreatorFn.
//   - No PGP Public Key given and the `cypher=off`-> returns Default vem.CreatorFn.
//   - Unknown rules combination detected -> returns vem.ErrCannotCreateMarshaller.
func (c *Creator) Create(cypher enum.Cypher, enc enum.Enc, pgpPublicKey string) (vem.CreatorFn, error) {
    rules := c.registerRules(cypher, enc, pgpPublicKey)
    for _, r := range rules {
        if r.cond() {
            return r.strategy()
        }
    }

    return nil, merry.Wrap(vem.ErrCannotCreateMarshaller, merry.AppendMessage("marshaller not found"))
}

func (c *Creator) registerRules(cypher enum.Cypher, enc enum.Enc, pgpPublicKey string) [4]rule {
    resolvers := [...]rule{
        {
            cond:     noPGPPublicKeyGivenWithEnabledOpenPGPCypher(cypher, pgpPublicKey),
            strategy: errPGPPublicKeyIsNotProvided,
        },
        {
            cond:     pgpPublicKeyGivenWithDisabledOpenPGPCypher(cypher, pgpPublicKey),
            strategy: errNoCypherSpecified,
        },
        {
            cond:     pgpPublicKeyGivenWithEnabledOpenPGPCypher(cypher, enc, pgpPublicKey),
            strategy: createCyphered(pgpPublicKey),
        },
        {
            cond:     noPGPPublicKeyGivenWithDisabledOpenPGPCypher(cypher, pgpPublicKey),
            strategy: createDefault,
        },
    }

    return resolvers
}
```

I'd move it one step forward to use the `Command` & `Command Handler` pattern, but for now I'll live it as it is.

Comment: Until someone else answers the question, you can actually edit the code in your question and replace it with the refactored code.